# Creating java objects with JQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I wanted to know if it's possible to create java objects and add the to an arraylist with JQuery.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

All of this is in my HTML page

```
<%
ArrayList<Project> projects= new ArrayList<Project>();
%>
```

And my JQuery function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){                     
          $(function(){
              $("#vt").click(function(e){
                   var name = $('#pn').val();
                   var desc = $('#pb').val();
                   Project p = new Project(name, desc);
                   projects.add(p);
              });
          });
    });
</script>
```

Is this possible? And if not, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: nop. jquery is frontend, java is backend. you should reach backend maybe with an ajax request on click

Comment: @Simze It's for a profile page. So I want to add project objects to the arraylist after the user presses 'save' at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @pumpkinzzz is there a way to add these objects to the arraylist without having to reload the page?

Comment: Both are different languages it's not possible to do that. You should use ajax call and make update at server side.

Comment: Is it possible to create java objects without having to reload the page?

Comment: yes @Bas, like i told you before: make an ajax call with jquery to the server, then in java create that object. that won't reload page, ajax it's asynchronous

Comment: @pumpkinzzz yes sorry, I don't have any experience with ajax yet, so I hoped there was another solution. It's no problem though! It's good to learn new things! Thank you!

Comment: @Bas i think is the only possible solution for you purposes. unless you're using [JSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces), that has cool ajax functions to manage java objects from frontend

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that directly. JQuery is frontend and Java is mainly backend.

I would suggest you to provide a REST-Service from the Java-side and call it from JQuery.

Java Spring-Boot 1.33 REST-Service example:

```
@RequestMapping("/rest/project")
public class ProjectController {
  @ResponseBody
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Response project(@RequestBody String name, @RequestBody String desc) {
     Project project = new Project(name, desc);
     //add to project to list
  }
}
```

The JQuery/Ajax part for rest consumation could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://example.com/rest/project"
  }).then(function(data) {
   $('.project-name').append(data.name);
   $('.project-desc').append(data.desc);
  });
});
```

Here is a full guide of what I proposed. [Spring-Boot-REST-JQuery](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/)